# Does the JVM / x86 guarantee non-volatile propagation of values across cores?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, jvm, java-memory-model

Assuming the following code:

```
class X {
    private int v = 1;
    public void set(int v) { this.v = v; }
    public int get() { return v; }
}
```

is there any possibility that by not having marked `v` as volatile, when calling `set(123)` its value will not propagate to other cores (that is, their caches and / or main-memory), or is it just a matter of time until that happens?

By asking around, the general idea seems to be that sooner or later the value "will get there", so as long as we don't care too much time-preciseness, it's OK to leave the value non-volatile, but I wanted to be formally sure.

My understanding is that as there's no acquire / release semantics, the JMM doesn't guarantee this to work, but on the other hand, my (limited) understanding of cache coherence / consistency models (namely, TSO-x86) is that it will necessarily eventually propagate (marking it as volatile would simply put a fence to disallow reorderings in the CPU's store-buffer but other than that it will eventually be propagated to other caches). Regarding this, there's only one point that makes me wonder -- what happens if another core writes something to another variable in the same cache line? Can it in any case overwrite `v`?

Can anyone knowledgeable on the matters give me a more concrete answer?

Thanks!

Comment: Once a memory store instruction is executed on x86, the value will be eventually visible by all cores. But the problem is that `set` and `get` methods don't even have to perform a real memory access when the field is non-volatile. I mean, JVM is free to eliminate a field store at all, if it sees that the value is not read afterwards in the same thread, e.g. if `set` method is called in an infinite loop. At least some JVMs (Excelsior JET) employ such optimizations in practice.

Comment: The question is, what “sooner or later” means. When you have code calling `set(123)` followed by an infinite loop, even a conservative optimizer might move the actual memory write behind the loop, so it did not eliminate it, still, it’s rather “later” than “sooner” and only Chuck Norris may eventually perceive the write (after the infinite loop has finished)…

Comment: It gets more interesting if you have two variables. Suppose that thread A updates `v` first and then `w`. How large is the window of time in which thread B could see one of the updates but not the other? Does it matter to your program if that happens? Would it be bad if thread B saw the second update (`w`) but not the first update  (`v`)? Synchronization problems become way more urgent when you talk about _relationships_ between shared variables. (e.g., imagine what could happen if thread A updates a linked data structure, but thread B sees only _some_ of the pointers changed.)

Comment: "_disallow reorderings in the CPU's store-buffer_" By definition there is no such thing on that CPU!

Comment: @Holger "Infinite loop" means code w/o any I/O, no mutex, no synchronization, correct?

Comment: @curiousguy exactly. Any kind of code making no progress over time, without imposing any memory visibility constraints. Note that also `Thread.sleep(…)` belongs to this category, as it is specified to have no memory visibility effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According the [memory model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4) of the JVM there is no [happens-before](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) relation in your example. Thus formally there is no gurantee that another thread will see updates to a shared variables ever.

Relying on implementation details of a particular JVM and processor architecture does not seem like a good idea to me. What works today in the lab might fail in the field tomorrow. Also note, that *eventually* might be a very long time as there is no upper bound to it. In fact I've experienced cases where my programme seemingly blocked due to missing `volatile` annotations and had to be restarted.

Comment: I agree with your first paragraph. My understanding of x86 tells me though that your second paragraph (taking a long time) should not ever happen. But I may be wrong and hence my creation of this question!

Comment: @devouredelysium, I'd say the answer is a "weak yes" for all practical cases. Although I've had cases where this didn't seem to happen in a practical time. Also I think you could construct a case where it would never happen: write a programme that stalls all other activity after updating `v` except for repeatedly trying to read `v`. In that case there is no need at all to propagete a new value to the cache.

Comment: I assume you mean that coreA writes to v and then repeatedly reads v, while all other cores don't do anything related to v, is that correct? But if that's the case, then I really don't care.

Comment: @devouredelysium, yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: Yes, as long as no one asks to read the cache-line it will just stay there forever in coreA, you are correct.

Comment: @devouredelysium there is no point in reasoning what the x86 architecture guarantees for the caches, when the JVM does not even guaranty that the value will ever reach the cache. E.g. it may keep the value in a CPU register instead. [As said by apangin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56001665/does-the-jvm-x86-guarantee-non-volatile-propagation-of-values-across-cores#comment98653840_56001665), a write may get eliminated entirely, if a JVM can prove that no subsequent operation enforces it. For the optimizer, only the JMM matters. The underlying architecture only sees the optimizer’s result

Answer (score 2):

It's dangerous to reason about the correctness of your code by gleaning at the underlying implementation details of a particular architecture. The JMM does not make any visibility guarantees across threads for non-volatile accesses. Just because it may work, doesn't mean it is always guaranteed to work.

Also, what's missing from your analysis is what the compiler might generate. The compiler might cache values in a register, might produce "spurious" reads or writes that don't affect the correctness of single-threaded programs, but break multi-threaded programs, etc.

If you want to guarantee visibility across threads without using volatile, take a look at Java 9's opaque access mode.